# How to create Multithreaded Dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, multithreading, dll

I have Dll that reads file from disk and returns it's content:

mydll.h:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InitFile3dPoints(wchar_t* i_file);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetNumPointsForSurface(int i_surf_index);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetPointsForSurface
    (double* o_result, int i_resultLength, int i_surf_index);
```

mydll.cpp:

```
File3dPoints file_3dPoints;

void InitFile3dPoints(wchar_t* i_file) 
          { file_3dPoints = readFile3dObjectFromDisk(i_file) }
int GetNumPointsForSurface(int i_surf_index) 
          { return file_3dPoints[i_surf_index].getNumPoints(); }

void GetPointsForSurface(double* o_result, int i_resultLength, int i_surf_index);
{
  const int num_points = file_3dPoints[i_surf_index].getNumPoints();
  if (num_points < i_resultLength)
    return;

  for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i)
    o_result[i] = file_3dPoints[i_surf_index].getPoint(i);
}
```

client.cs:

```
IntPtr inst = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
InitFile3dPoints(filename);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  int num_points_for_surface = GetNumPointsForSurface(i);
  double[] points = new double[num_points_for_surface];
  GetPointsForSurface(points, points.Length, i);
  // some code
}
FreeLibrary(inst);
```

My dll is not thread-safe. One thread can call InitFile3dPoints. And before calling GetPointsForSurface another thread can call InitFile3dPoints.
Could you plase advise me how do make it thread-safe? Creating mutex for accessing file_3dPoints will not solve the problem, I need every thread that comes in mydll.cpp to have its copy of file_3dPoints.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many options to do that.

First and most important do not use global variables, they're a nightmare (for this and other reasons). Let's start to change `InitFile3dPoints` signature to allocate the required memory and to return it to the caller (so the address can be used as "handle"):

```
File3dPoints* InitFile3dPoints(const wchar_t* i_file) 
{
    return readFile3dObjectFromDisk(i_file);
}
```

Please note that `readFile3dObjectFromDisk` must return a heap allocated object of type `File3dPoints`.

Then change each function to accept that pointer:

```
int GetNumPointsForSurface(const File3dPoints* data, int i_surf_index) 
{
    return *data[i_surf_index].getNumPoints(); 
}
```

`File3dPoints*` can be marshaled in C# with `IntPtr`:

```
IntPtr inst = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
IntPtr data = InitFile3dPoints(filename);
```

Finally do not forget to add a `DisposeFile3dPoints` function where you deallocate data:

```
void DisposeFile3dPoints(File3dPoints* data)
{
    if (data != NULL)
        delete data;
}
```

In general to make a DLL "thread-safe" (according to the context of your question) you should make each function self-contained (all the data it needs comes from its parameters, it doesn't have any local static variable nor global ones). Please note that this doesn't make it really thread-safe in any wider sense (if, for example, you'll expose a write function to that data then you'll still need to protect access but it can be done more easily in the C# side).

You can do even better wrapping all these functions inside a C# class, users won't even see that:

```
public class File3D : IDisposable
{
    public File3D(string path)
    {
        // Initialize. Call InitFile3dPoints
    }

    ~File3D()
    {
        // Call Dispose(false)
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private IntPtr _data;

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Unmanaged resource, ignore disposing parameter
        // and call DisposeFile3dPoints
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer, have solved my long lasting problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Protect access to global variables using a mutex. Better yet, don't use global variables.

Comment: or if possible use std::atomic

Comment: Don't use std::atomic and don't use a mutex. Simply stop using globals. Locks should be shunned if possible. They hinder scaling. So, in a situation like this where locks are not needed, don't use them!

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your code so that `InitFile3dPoint()` returns a `File3dPoints` that you then pass to the other functions as context. The typical approach is to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance. You then have to take care of proper ownership and deallocation management, but you make the DLL itself thread-safe even without any mutex.